# Passing a string through 2 modal segues

Tags: ios, swift

I have been struggling to implement an example of protocol and delegate.

My MainVC has a Modal Segue to a CategoryVC but the CategoryVC sends the user to a DetailVC.

I need to set the MainVC as the delegate for the DetailVC, but all of the examples I can find set the MainVC as the delegate of the DetailVC when the MainVC instantiates the DetailVC.
My DetailVC is not instantiated by the MainVC.

I want to accomplish

```
detailVC.delegate = self
```

But because I'm using Interface Builder Modal Segues, I don't know how to refer to the object.

Edit:
MainVC has an image being edited and the functionality to add overlays
CategoryVC has categories of overlays
DetailVC has a UICollectionView showing all of the overlays to choose from

I want DetailVC to pass to MainVC which overlay to add to the image

Comment: Do you really need to use a protocol for this? You could accomplish passing the string with a property and a segue from code

Comment: I can segue from DetailVC to MainVC?
I don't need to dismiss CategoryVC and DetailVC?

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're trying to do. Can you edit the post with more information about how the app is supposed to flow?

Comment: Edited with more detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the sequence goes `MainVC` (modal segue) -> `CategoryVC` (Modal segue) -> `DetailVC`

It sounds like `CategoryVC` needs to relay the info about mainVC to DetailVC.

You could give `CategoryVC` a property `theMainVC` that it would use to remember the MainVC.

So in `MainVC`'s prepareForSegue:

```
func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
   if let theCategoryVC = segue.destination as? CategoryVC {
     theCategoryVC.theMainVC = self
   }
}
```

Then in your `CategoryVC`:

```
var theMainVC: MainVC?

func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
   if let theDetailVC = segue.destination as? DetailVC {
     theDetailVC.delegate = theMainVC
   }
}
```

Comment: Nailed it! I have some extensions that added some complexity, but your examples were very clear.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There are many solutions to your current problem

1- Chain delegate

```
protocol MYDataSender {
   func myDele(str:String)
} 
class MainVC:UIViewController,MYDataSender{

  func myDele(str:String) { print(str) }
}
```

when present CategoryVC

```
let cat = ///
cat.delegate = self // if you don't use self.present(vc ,,, then it would be inside prepareForSegue

class CategoryVC:UIViewController{
   var delegate:MYDataSender!
}
```

when present DetailsVC

```
let det = //
det.delegete = delegate // rhs is CategoryVC'sdelegete = MainVC , if you don't use self.present(vc ,,, then it would be inside prepareForSegue

class DetailsVC:UIViewController{
   var delegate:MYDataSender!
   func send() {
     delegate.myDele(str:"sendToMain")
   }
}
```

2- NotificationCenter // the easiest

3- Shared singleton

4- Store Data